# How to scatter plot if X and Y are of unequal size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to scatter plots X and Y using matplotlib. but i dot know how to scatter plots if X & Y are of unequal size.

The size of x is (1309, 8) and
size of y is (1309,)

Comment: Well, what is your plot supposed to represent? You've got 8 `values` for each `y`, so maybe just one of them is the correct one etc.

Comment: Presumably you need replicates of y to match x? What have you tried so far? Why not just iterate over `range(8)` and use the index to generate a single column for `x` and match it each time with the same `y`?

Comment: `plt.scatter(x, np.tile(y, 8))` could work, depending on what it is you want to show.

Comment: @JohanC maybe `plt.scatter(x.ravel(),...`